# What does 'inconsistent line ending' mean in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

What does 'inconsistent line ending' mean in Visual Studio 2010?

I also see this error in a dialog when I'm coding in VS2010. How can I stop this error from showing in the dialog?

Comment: This happens with VS2005 and VS2008 as well, not specific to VS2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Windows, Unix, and older Mac OSs use different line endings](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html). (Newer MacOS uses the Unix convention).

Windows uses CR/LF, Unix uses only LF.

Visual Studio is telling you it found messed up line endings on your file, indicating it was probably edited on different operating systems, and has fixed them all for you to be consistent. If you're getting that message more than once per file, then you have to stop whatever is causing the line endings to get borked in the first place, which is most likely not Visual Studio but some other editor.

Comment: What would be nice would be a 'don't bug me about this' option, maybe a registry hack...

Comment: @Chris: Why would you want it to not tell you? Either unix or windows line endings are fine. Mixing them in the same file is just stupid.

Comment: Different line endings in the same file, no that's a real problem! I was talking about when one file in another teams project has different line endings, it's really annoying having to do a full rebuild just for that. Of course we both know what the real answer to that is ;-)

Comment: @Chris: That's not what the OP is talking about. The "Inconsistent Line Endings" dialog box is shown only when a single file has differing line endings.

Comment: @Chris: You can disable such checking under Tools -> Options, and then navigating to Environment\Documents. There is a checkbox for "Check for inconsistent line endings on load".

Answer (score 2):

Billy and Sean has already described the cause of the problem, however one potential fix is to set up your version control system to enforce the correct line endings for .h and .cpp files.  For instance if you're using Subversion then this is a matter of setting the `svn:eol-style` property to `native`.  You can also do `File -> Advanced Save Options` to force the EOL style for each file you have problems with.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's response from http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/538108/inconsistent-line-endings-dialogue-in-ide:

> What that usually means is that you have lines ending with something other than a carriage return/line feed pair. It often happens when you copy and paste from a web page into the code editor.
>
> Since you're developing in Visual Studio, you'll obviously want to choose "Windows" from the drop down.

Comment: my problem is when i open the file he show the error. i know the problem but how i can stop him for a long time then i work comfortably